# Why is filter(sorted(xs)) faster than sorted(filter(xs)) in Python?

Tags: python

sorting should be *O(n log n)* and filtering should be *O(n)*. why am i getting better performance for sorting first, when filtering would reduce the size of the list, thereby reducing the n before passing it into the sort?

consider this problem where text (attribution: [Wikipedia entry for "Grass Skiing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grass_skiing)) is filtered for words containing an "i" and sorted.

sorted(filter(xs))

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'text = "Grass skiing, skiing on grass is a method for training for alpine skiing Both grass skiing and alpine skiing have become established as sports in their own right The skis used for grass skiing are short with rolling treads or wheels These skis are attached to the skiers boots Depending on the skill of the grass skier high speeds and jumps can be navigated".split(" ")' 'sorted(filter(lambda s: s.find("i") >= 0, text))'

20000 loops, best of 5: 14.7 usec per loop
```

filter(sorted(xs))

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'text = "Grass skiing, skiing on grass is a method for training for alpine skiing Both grass skiing and alpine skiing have become established as sports in their own right The skis used for grass skiing are short with rolling treads or wheels These skis are attached to the skiers boots Depending on the skill of the grass skier high speeds and jumps can be navigated".split(" ")' 'filter(lambda s: s.find("i") >= 0, sorted(text))'

100000 loops, best of 5: 2.74 usec per loop
```

Comment: Possibly partially because `filter` doesn't do anything until you iterate through it.

Comment: may have something to do with how sort works on a generator and how it works on an array. For the former it cannot sort it in place

Comment: Yeah, you're not actually performing the filtering in the `filter(sorted(...))` case.

Comment: Stick a `list` call around it for a meaningful comparison.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3 here?

Comment: Okay, I can confirm that if I try it in python 2, in which `filter` will actually return a list and not just a generator, `filter(sorted(...))` is slower than `sorted(filter(...))` as expected. In python 3, as @khelwood says, you are not actually doing any filtering in the `filter(sorted(...))` case because you're not iterating over it yet.

Comment: Yep, that's what's going on - the return value from `filter` is just a generator, you haven't actually performed the `O(n)` operation on the return value here.

Comment: sneaky! thank you all for the clarification on the result type of filter.

Answer (score 0):

as reviewers in the comments pointed out, the result of `filter(sorted(xs))` is lazy and results in an iterator, but `sorted(filter(xs))` is eager and results in a collection type. to force the computation of the filter (in the former case), wrap the computation in a collection type such as a `list` or `tuple`: `tuple(filter(sorted(xs))`.

after making this change, my test case behaves as expected:

sorted(filter(xs))

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'text = "Grass skiing, skiing on grass is a method for training for alpine skiing Both grass skiing and alpine skiing have become established as sports in their own right The skis used for grass skiing are short with rolling treads or wheels These skis are attached to the skiers boots Depending on the skill of the grass skier high speeds and jumps can be navigated".split(" ")' 'sorted(filter(lambda s: s.find("i") >= 0, text))'
20000 loops, best of 5: 16 usec per loop
```

filter(sorted(xs))

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'text = "Grass skiing, skiing on grass is a method for training for alpine skiing Both grass skiing and alpine skiing have become established as sports in their own right The skis used for grass skiing are short with rolling treads or wheels These skis are attached to the skiers boots Depending on the skill of the grass skier high speeds and jumps can be navigated".split(" ")' 'list(filter(lambda s: s.find("i") >= 0, sorted(text)))'
20000 loops, best of 5: 18.3 usec per loop
```